# Why is mouse freezing in FreeBSD 9.1 Gnome or Fluxbox?

Tags: xorg, gnome, freebsd, mouse, fluxbox

I'm new to FreeBSD 9.1 and I wanted to install a desktop GUI environment. I first tried Gnome 2 since I am familiar with it. I appended the following lines to the /etc/rc.conf file:

```
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
gnome_enable="YES"
gdm_enable="YES"
```

When typing `startx` for the first time, my mouse, keyboard and everything else worked fine. However, after restarting my PC, the mouse didn't work anymore. Keyboard worked fine. I searched around for solutions and people said that adding the following line to the /etc/rc.conf file

```
mouse_enable="YES"
```

or

```
moused_enable="YES"
```

worked for them. However, this didn't work for me. I then tried switching to Fluxbox just to check if that works. I appended the following lines to the /etc/rc.conf file:

```
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
```

Again, when typing `startx` for the first time, my mouse and keyboard worked fine. However, after restarting my PC again the mouse worked just before starting X (in text mode). However, after starting X it doesn't work at all. Keyboard works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this kind of behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you restart after editing rc.conf?

Comment: @schaiba yes, I restarted... several times

Answer (score 0):

I just "figured" this out, but more investigation would indeed lead to a real fix.
When you come out of X, restart your hald service.

This cleared it up for me.

-jgh

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.